# Translating data points to pixel coordinates for drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, math, drawing, pixel

I have a `PictureBox` and I want to draw a diode curve by knowing its data points (X,Y of points). At the moment my picturebox is sized 365*468 pixels. I am scratching my head to translate data points I have to pixel friendly values so the curve draws nicely on the picture box.

So far I have tried various formulas but no success! At the moment I am stuck in ths code, it atleast showsa little bit of curve!

```
    private PointF[] TranslatePoints(PointF[] points)
    {
        var count = points.Count();
        var p = new PointF[count];

        for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            p[i].X = DrawingArea.Width * (1 + (points[i].X / _voltageRange));
            p[i].Y = DrawingArea.Height * (1 - (points[i].Y * (float)Math.Pow(_currentRange, -1)));
        }

        return p;
    }
```

`_voltageRange` and `_currentRange` are the scale I want the curve to be based on...it is usually is +2 that should mean values on X axis should be drawn if they are between -2 and +2, for the current that is Y axis values should be drawn for example if they are between -10 micro and +10 u

I want this method to be as standalone as possible so if I resize the picturebox the scale updates correctly.

This is for example the first data point I have of the real values : (-0.6375, -0.00000993375) and my method translates it to (24.515625, 932.899536) which is out of the size piturebox.

Normally a diode curve looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!!! I had to divide Width and height by 2 in the formula I used! like this:

```
   p[i].X = (DrawingArea.Width/2F) * (1 + (points[i].X / _voltageRange)); 
   p[i].Y = (DrawingArea.Height/2F) * (1 - (points[i].Y * (float)Math.Pow(_currentRange, -1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aftre scaling the coordinates you need to move back the shape as it will be bigger, but on the other side the starting position will be different, so after scaling up, you need to pull the shape back to the original starting position.
So you need to define a starting position which coul be the most left bottom point. After that you can check the X/Y difference of the original and the scaled up coordinate and correct the other points with these values like:

```
var leftBottomPointOriginal = LeftBottom(points)
var leftBottomPointScaledUp= LeftBottom(scaledUpPoints)

var xCorrection = leftBottomPointScaledUp.X-leftBottomPointOriginal.X
var yCorrection = leftBottomPointScaledUp.Y-leftBottomPointOriginal.Y


 for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            p[i].X = DrawingArea.Width * (1 + (points[i].X / _voltageRange))-xCorrection;
            p[i].Y = DrawingArea.Height * (1 - (points[i].Y * (float)Math.Pow(_currentRange, -1)))-yCorrection;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain what should I assign to `leftBottomPointOriginal` and `leftBottomPointScaledUp` ?? I did not get the idea!

Comment: i think here you should position to the center, so get the point of the 0,0 position on the graph. If you scale up the real coordinates, then you can check the differences and reposition the graph to the center.

Comment: well it was simpler than that , my original approach was correct I just had to divide wirdth and height by 2 in my equation! any way thanks.